# concatenate records in columnar format in jcl

Tags: mainframe

I have 4 files which have different records:

File 1

```
12345
34567
12300
21345
```

File 2

```
89090
98765
45674
23421
```

File 3

```
21356
34560
43121
11223
```

File 4

```
98765
12345
12214
```

I want output should be

```
12345 | 89090 | 21356 | 98765
....
```

and so on

I am trying to add sequence number to each file like start with 00 and increment by 25
but unable to build
Please help how to acheive in JCL sort card

I have tried with inrec sequence number not able proceed then

Answer (score 1):

With files that size, it's easier to just edit the files directly and use your emulator's copy/paste function to combine the files.